# Faire un / le plombage

Tags: articles

J'ai cherché ces deux tournures sur Internet. Il y a beaucoup plus de résultats avec l'article indéfini, *faire **un** plombage*, mais *faire **le** plombage* s'emploie aussi.

Est-il possible de dire en général *Il a fait **le** plombage* ou *Le dentiste me fera **le** plombage demain*, ou *faire **le** plombage* serait-il une faute ?

Comment: L'article défini ou indéfini couvrent des situations différentes. Le dentiste va me faire un plombage demain. Le plombage sera en or. Mais: on peut également dire: va me faire le plombage demain dans une discussion déjà entamée....

Answer (score 2):

Les articles définis et indéfinis couvrent des situations différentes.

> Le dentiste va me faire **un** plombage demain. **Le** plombage sera en or.

Mais, dans une discussion déjà entamée, on peut également dire :

> Il va me faire **le** plombage demain.

<sub>Note: commentaire de Lambie converti en réponse</sub>.

Comment: _dans une discussion déjà entamée_ Cela veut dire qu'il est possible de dire _faire **le** plombage_ uniquement  si ce plombage a déjà été mentionné ? Et si, par exemple, deux personnes parlent, disons A. dit à B. qu'il a un RV demain chez son dentiste, lui dit d'autres choses au sujet de ce dentiste ou ses dents, dans ce cas-là, est-il possible de dire _Il va me faire **le** plombage demain_ ? // Que veut dire _community wiki_, mis à par les votes ?

Comment: Il ne peut dire *il va me faire le plombage* que si ce plombage a été récemment mentionné dans la conversation. *Community wiki* signifie simplement que la réponse n'est pas endossée par quelqu'un en particulier et pour souligner que tout le monde est libre d'enrichir la réponse (ce dernier point étant en fait le cas pour toutes les réponses). Ici, Lambie avait fourni une réponse dans un commentaire. Je l'ai reprise en "vraie" réponse, là où elle aurait dû être, mais sans m'en attribuer la paternité.

Comment: L'article indéfini/défini suit le même chemin presque toujours, dans toutes les langues pour des exemples comparables. On commence par l'indéfini et puis on change d' article. Ceci est sûrement un défi pour ceux qui parlent une langues sans articles.